# How can I make Java add to a private int mouseClicks every second?

Tags: java, jgrasp

```
public class Blank extends WindowController
{
    private int mouseClicks;

    public void onMousePress(Location point)
    {
         mouseClicks++;
    }
}
```

My goal is for if mouseClicks to increment once every second, while while only having to click once to start it.

Comment: I think I might have understood your question. Do you wish to ensure that `mouseClicks` can only increase at a maximum of once per second, or have it increment once a second automatically?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the best solution I can get.

```
public class Blank extends WindowController
{
    private final AtomicInteger mouseClicks = new AtomicInteger();
    private boolean hasStarted = false;

    public void onMousePress(Location point)
    {
       if(!hasStarted){
         hasStarted = true;
         Thread t = new Thread(){
             public void run(){
                 while(true){
                     mouseClicks.incrementAndGet(); //adds one to integer
                     Thread.sleep(1000); //surround with try and catch
                 }
             }
         };
         t.start();
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: This isn't thread-safe if code outside the increment thread wants to read `mouseClicks`. Consider replacing the `int` with an [`AtomicInteger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) as the easiest way to get thread-safety.

Comment: edited for use with AtomicInteger, but couldn't other people just add more to the AtomicInteger? That wouldn't make it more thread-safe than ints? Im confused now XD

Comment: The int value would not have been [visible to other threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/memconsist.html) on its own. Making it a `volatile int` would have solved that, actually, so the `AtomicInteger` is not necessarily the simplest solution, but it is if other code also wanted to update the value, because `volatile`, on its own, does not provide an atomic increment operation, so would not prevent [thread interference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interfere.html).

Comment: Good point. Thanks for the break-down. I guess it is the matter of what the original poster prefers and wants.

Answer (score 0):

Look into using `Thread.sleep(1000);` to pause execution for one second.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html

Comment: Wouldn't this prevent other kinds of events in the awt thread from being fired?

Comment: @AlexT. OP hasn't said what UI toolkit they're using. It doesn't look like AWT, but yeah, Thread.sleep will probably block event dispatch, so it's no good. OP needs to use whatever the equivalent of [javax.swing.Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) is in their UI toolkit.

Answer (score -1):

You could test the time passed since the last click.

```
long lLastClickTime = Long.MIN_VALUE;

public void onMousePress(Location point) {
   final long lCurrentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
   if(lCurrentTime - lClickLastTime >= 1000) {
      mouseClicks++;
      lLastClickTime = lCurrentTime;
   }         
}
```